# In the US, which shares should I sell if I want to keep the most compounding effect?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, wash-sale

This is for the US.

I have been doing DCA: Dollar Cost Averaging, so I have been buying Apple and Google (and some Amazon, QQQ, S&P500 ETF) regularly, perhaps $100 per day, in my regular personal account. (not IRA).

Due to the massive layoffs in the high tech industry, I may need to spend 2, 3 months to look for the next job, so I may need $2000 or $3000 meanwhile to pay for bills, and buy them back 2, 3 months later when I find a job.

In that case, when I sell my shares of Apple or Google (or Amazon or S&P500), I have the following choices:

1. shares that I bought in January - March 2024, which is
   a. breaking even (no rise and no drop from the price I purchased)
   b. Same as above but dropped 3% or less
   c. Same as above but dropped 3% or more (hypothetically)
   d. Same as above but rose 3%
   e. Same as above but rose more than 3%
2. shares that I bought within 12 months (so after March 2023), and is
   (a) to (e) the same as above, with (a) breaking even, (b) dropped less than 3%, etc
3. shares that I bought and are longer than 12 months, say within these two years
   (a) to (e) the same as above
4. shares that I bought 3 - 5 years ago
   (a) to (e) the same as above

Which shares should I sell so that I pay least tax and I think the final goal is to maximize the long term compounding?

My thoughts is that, it may be best to sell all the ones that are "breaking even" (the short term ones) first, so that it is as if I never bought them, and pay no tax.

If I sell some short term ones, even if it is very little profits, I am subject to paying tax immediately or within 2024. (as it is taxed as if it is wages, not as long term capital gain).

If I sell the ones that has some gains and are long term, it has a lower tax rate, but then it will make the compounding effect less, due to tax.

If I sell the ones that has some loss, I am afraid that if I buy them back in April, I may be subject to the wash sale rule. (which is: I cannot claim the loss so in effect, it is like, I may end up with a higher cost for the future shares, because I lost those claim for losses).

There also is some complication because after the previous job has ended, I can transfer some money over from my last job's 401k Roth which is limited to S&P500 and T Rowe Price Tech fund and Retirement Target 2030, 2035, etc, to a personal Roth IRA, so that I can buy Apple or Google or QQQ. So while I may not buy back the shares until May or June, but with this transfer of fund, I actually may use that fund to buy Apple or Google in March and April (within this 30 days). So I am not sure if this will put me as doing a "wash sale".

What may be a proper way or correct way to share these shares for temporary living expenses?

Comment: If you have multiple shares of a the same company bought at different times at different prices then from an investment perspective right now all the shares are completely equivalent and the question 'which ones do I sell' doesn't mean anything. It makes a differences for taxes, so I assume that is what you are interested in?

Comment: right, on some investment firm's website, when you sell, you can specify "Sell the ones purchased on Feb 5, 2024, etc. Otherwise, they assume it is "FIFO", meaning selling the oldest shares I bought (and if that has a lot of gain, then you have to pay tax on those gain now, instead of in 2030 or 2035 when you retire)

Comment: @StefanieGauss As a side note - it is generally not wise to make stock investments before you have some amount of cash savings, for just such a situation as this. The possible exception would be that if you are making investments in a work retirement plan, where your employer will only fund your account by matching your contributions.

Comment: If there are losing positions, when you consider which shares to sell, make sure that you do not incur wash sales.  If you do, you'll  temporarily lose the ability to deduct some/all of the loss until the replacement shares are sold.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I have savings... that's why now I am trying to come up with 2 to 3 thousand dollars. If I didn't have savings, I'd right now try to come up with $8000 to $10000... it is expensive to live in California

Comment: @BobBaerker so I think if I am selling the shares for $172.50, then I need to choose shares I bought for $172.50 or $172.63 or $173... etc. I just need to assume for those tiny losses, I will not be able to claim them

Comment: Have you considered taking some money out of your Roth?  ["You can withdraw a sum equivalent to the contributions from a Roth 401(k) without paying a penalty or taxes because Roth contributions are made with after-tax dollars."](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/101314/what-are-roth-401k-withdrawal-rules.asp) I am not a tax attorney, but that agrees with what I understand.  Or you could borrow from it.

Comment: @JimmyJames: All the lost compounding the question worries about applies to a Roth IRA as well... except now you're losing compounding of gains that will never be taxed.  So that's much much worse than selling equity from a taxable account.

Comment: Shares of the same company are fungible so it makes no difference which Apple shares you sell. Selling 100 shares purchased at $150 versus selling 100 shares purchased at $155 does not alter your future compounding (which shares you sell, not the act of selling). If you are trying to determine in terms of compounding whether it will be better to sell AAPL or to sell GOOG, that cannot be determined because the future is unknown.

Comment: *If I sell the ones that has some gains and are long term, it has a lower tax rate, but then it will make the compounding effect less, due to tax.* - what does this mean? I'm not sure you're using the word "compounding" right.

Comment: @littleadv it is the basic understanding that, say if you can compound at 10% per year. But if you have to pay tax, say, for 33%, so now you are compounding only at 6.67% per year. At 10%, you can double your money in about 7 years. At 6.67%, you can double your money in about 11 years

Comment: @BenVoigt The OP talked about using selling the shares and then using things in the Roth to buy them back.  Also, S&P500 is far less volatile than the individual stocks and therefore less likely to make a big move over the timeframes in question.

Comment: @StefanieGauss: Tax is only taken out of compounding when there are distributions and a DRIP program.  Capital gains fully compound, and then you pay capital gains tax on the final balance.  But this is a difference between different ticker symbols (some stocks and funds pay distributions, some don't) and not a difference between lots of the same ticker.

Comment: @JimmyJames: The question clearly talks about using future income to buy them back in the taxable account.  The retirement account seems to be mentioned because of the (correct) concern that the rollover there can create wash sales.

Comment: @BenVoigt "I can transfer some money over from my last job's 401k Roth which is limited to S&P500 and T Rowe Price Tech fund and Retirement Target 2030, 2035, etc, to a personal Roth IRA, **so that I can buy Apple or Google or QQQ.**"

Comment: @JimmyJames: That quote appears between "There also is some complication because ... I am not sure if this will put me as doing a wash sale".  That is not intended to be the replacement of the shares sold.  Look much earlier in the question: "I may need $2000 or $3000 meanwhile to pay for bills, and buy them back 2, 3 months later when I find a job."

Comment: @BenVoigt "That is not intended to be the replacement of the shares sold." That doesn't make much sense.  Why would you assume selling shares and rebuying the same thing (potentially a wash sale) is not intended to replace the shares.  Are you saying that you think selling Apple and then rebuying it right away is some sort of random coincidence?

Comment: @JimmyJames: Yes, it can be a coincidence.  Moving money between two providers, or rolling 401(k) over into IRA, even though it involves sale and repurchase, has a completely different intent compared to increasing or decreasing investment of a particular holding.  And the intent is even more distinct between the retirement account rollover vs the taxable account meeting short-term expenses.

Comment: Ok, it's not uncorrelated, because the rolling over a 401(k) and the short-term expenses are both triggered by the same event of leaving a job.  But in the abstract of intentions, you have to look at OP's retirement account rollover completely separately from their management of taxable account.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think it's up to the OP to clarify the intentions.  If these aren't related, I'm not sure why it's mentioned at all.  If you are sure there's no wash sale applicability, then maybe add an answer.

Comment: @JimmyJames I thought my intention is super simple and crystal clear: I want to roll those 401k over so that I can invest in anything (more choices, more flexible). I need to sell a little bit of holdings because I need some short term expense money

Comment: That's clear.  What's not clear is why you mention selling specific securities in the non-sheltered account and then purchasing those same securities in the sheltered account.  I was thinking there might be a way to get that same result without generating a taxable event but the goofy tax rules around these accounts don't seem to allow for that.

Comment: @JimmyJames: It's true that OP didn't explain that, but I think it's self-evident.  OP can only sell from the non-sheltered account the stocks owned there.  Meaning they are stocks and funds Stefanie believed are worth investing in.  Which is the same criterion (possibly with a different time horizon) which would naturally be used to choose what to buy in the retirement account after rollover.  I too have a lot of overlapping holdings between sheltered and non-sheltered accounts, because they're what I expect to grow in value.

Comment: But it doesn't mean there's any attempt to transfer or replace from non-sheltered to sheltered account.  It just means that the same question is asked twice, for two different pools of money, and gives the same answer twice.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've accepted that I read too much into it. It just seemed like there might be a goal of selling but not really selling.  If you are forced to sell equities under duress, it kind of makes sense to try to figure out how to do it without losing ground.  It's OK, I'm used to seeing things differently than everyone else. Sometimes it's useful but often not.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is lengthy so I feel like you are over complicating things. Generally, you want to sell losses first, then gains, while also taking short/long term holdings into consideration. This means you sell in this order:

1. Short-term losses
2. Long-term losses
3. Long-term gains
4. short-term gains

This gives you the best tax treatment when selling. Although, as @Ben Voigt said in a comment, if you have a year with much lower income it might make sense in the long run to sell your long-term gains sooner since they might be taxed at 0%.

If by "keep the most compounding" you mean "have the most potential for growth" it doesn't really matter. If I have one share bought for $100 and another bought for $120 but the current price is $130; if I sell today I get $130. The only difference is what I pay in taxes. The "age" of the stock doesn't change what the potential growth is *from today*.

Comment: Except that tax bracket is based on net income, so a year with partial unemployment might be better for taking the gains than holding them and paying in a year of higher income and a higher rate.

Comment: I do agree 100% with the final paragraph however.

Comment: what about break-evens? Do they take precedence over losses?

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. If I hold $1000 worth of Apple, but sold it this year and have to pay tax, and I can only buy back $800 worth of it two months later, sure my compounding is affected, because 20 years later, instead of holding N shares, I will only be holding 0.8N shares

Comment: @StefanieGauss: You're both right: The "it doesn't matter" is measuring in number of shares.  The future growth of any one share is equal to future growth of any other one share.  However, the dollars you get from that one share to use immediately for expenses do depend on how much tax you owe.  Either way, you have to pay tax on today's gain "someday", but because of time value of money, it's better to pay a smaller fraction of that today, and a larger fraction far in the future.